# On some finite 2-group of class two

Tags: group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On automorphism of some finite 2-group of class nilpotency two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154583/on-automorphism-of-some-finite-2-group-of-class-nilpotency-two)

Let $G$ be a finite 2-group of nilpotency  class  two such that $\frac{G}{Z(G)}\simeq C_{2}\times C_{2}$. Then do there exist a non inner automorphism of $G$ that acts trivial only on $Z(G)$?
For example  $D_{8}$,  dihedral group of order 8, has a non inner automorphism that acts trivial only on $Z(G)$.